# call JavaScript function after cookie is loaded

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this piece of code i use to show users facebook like popup only if they didn't see it before. the code is pretty straight forward and goes as follows:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    var expireTime = time + 1*36000;
    now.setTime(expireTime);

    document.cookie = 'seen_fb_like=true;cookie=ok;expires='+now.toGMTString()+';path=/';
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + cname + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

window.onload = function() {
    var seen = getCookie("seen_fb_like");
    if(!seen) {
    document.getElementById('popup-container').style.display = ("block");
    setCookie();
}
}
```

on my local machine this code worked as wished but after deploying it to my server i see that every now and than i see the popup even after seeing it few seconds ago. i thought it might be because sometimes the `window.onload` function is executed before the cookie is loaded but than i couldn't find any documentation to agree with that...any idea how can i deal with this issue?

Comment: "i think it is because sometimes the window.onload function is executed before the cookie is loaded" — No, that can't happen.

Comment: Remove the path from the cookie.  If you navigate out of that path then the cookie won't exist any more.  If the path isn't there then it will be read for the whole domain.

Comment: Print the value of the cookie? Maybe it's not being set or being changed somewhere?

Comment: `("block")` the `(` and `)` are useless, get rid of them.

Comment: `var parts = value.split("; " + cname + "=");` seems like a BAD way to look for your cookie.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing asynchronously with reading a cookie value. So there is no issue with flow of the code.

The way you are determining if the cookie there is a flaw. If the cookie is the first value, your code will not detect it since there will be no semicolon there. So maybe that is why it does not work occasionally since it is the first item in the cookie.

Use a regular expression approach to check for the cookie. [MDN Simple Cookie Framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework) has examples.

```
var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return null; }
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  ...
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You can provide an overload of `getCookie` which accepts a callback function, and make that function execute explicitly after the required cookie has been retrieved.

Comment: I would appreciate if you also provided an explanation for the downvotes, this way I can also learn something.

Comment: Given that the cookie is already there, perhaps you could explain what you mean by "after the required cookie has been retrieved" and more about how a callback function will help.  Example code based on the OPs code would also be a more useful answer.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. My answer was based on the wrong assumption that the getCookie function is executed asynchronously.